# how to loop through list in a view returned by controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

My controller is returning following list :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    CRMDataContext mycontext=new CRMDataContext();

    var myquery = (from c in mycontext.Websites
                  select c).ToList();

    return View(myquery);
}
```

i'm wondering how can i loop through myquery to display its properties in view??

any suggestions for improving above code will be added advantage.

Comment: Did you try Json Result and tried to read the values in JQuery ?

Answer (score 4):

```
@foreach(var item in Model){
  ...
}
```

improvement suggestions:

- move your query in another method/class for core reusage
- separate responsibilities by using separate models for domain and view

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's best that you map your entity into a model and use the model in your view. Most importantly if you will not be using all the fields in your entity.

Suppose your entity has this structure:

```
public class Website {
  public string Title {get;set;}
  public string Url {get;set;}
  public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

In your view you can do something like:

```
@model IEnumerable<Website> // you may need to fully qualify it or add the namespace in your web.config
@foreach(var o in Model){
  <div>
     <h1><a href="@o.Url">@o.Title</a></h1>
     <p>@o.Description</p>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: When i tried your code im getting this error: foreach statement can not operate on variables of type Website because it doesnot contain a public defination for 'GenEnumerator'

Comment: Your code shows that you return a list of objects, and those objects are instances of `Website`. Isn't that right? I updated the model to be `IEnumerable<Website>`.

Comment: after changing @model header to IEnumerable im getting following error: : The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ImportFromExcel.Website]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ImportFromExcel.Models.Website]'.

Comment: i could solve it via this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705808/how-to-loop-through-list-returned-by-lambda-expression

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach loop:

```
@{
  foreach (var element in Model)
  {
      //Write you html code here.
  }
}
```